# how to set a wsdl for a soap server in python

Tags: python, soap, wsdl

I have wrote a python script for a SOAP server using `SOAPy`:

```
from SOAPpy import WSDL, SOAPProxy, SOAPServer, ThreadingSOAPServer, SOAPRequestHandler
import sys

class Hello(object):
    def hello(self):
        return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = SOAPServer(addr=('192.168.20.232', 8000))
    wsdl_file = '../wsdl/SendFaxService-me.xml'
    server = WSDL.Proxy(wsdl_file)
    server.show_methods()
    s.registerFunction(Hello().hello)
    s.serve_forever()
```

There is a WSDL file which I want to use for this server. But I don't know how to set a WSDL address for this server.